# Why is my Sim mean to his wife and kids?

Tags: the-sims-3

Yesterday I was playing Sims 3 pets and my Sim came home from work. His wife asked him how his day was and he yelled at her. His mood meter went up. His son asked him if he would play catch. My sim declined and then started playing video games on the T.V. When his daughter joined him, he stopped and started playing games on the computer. Why does my Sim do these things?

Comment: During all of this, his mood meter went up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Sims have high levels of Free Will they will do whatever they feel like doing. Social Interactions, even mean ones, will increase their Social meters but may damage their relationships with other Sims. Sims seem to choose their interactions with influence from their traits. Evil sims seem to be more prone to mean interactions than Good sims.

There isn't really any rhyme or reason why your Sim had these behaviors. The game is a simulation of human life, but not a perfect one. The next time the father sim interacts with with his family it may be positive or negative. Previous interactions only really affect future reactions if they change the relationship level from friends to enemies. Unless that happened, you cannot accurately predict what your sim will do next.

Comment: Okay, Do you think I’ll be able to stop him manually?

Comment: In your options menu you can lower his ability to have free will, and can more-directly control his actions. This would be physically stopping him from doing anything except from what actions you want him to take. Alternatively, you can keep his high free will and still control his actions. Queue up several positive interactions and let him be free afterwards, he'll likely continue positive interactions.

Comment: That sounds like it’ll stop his family’s mood meter from going down

Comment: This worked! He isn’t being so mean anymore and his family is happier around him!